# Angular Unit Test Component Callthrough On SpyObject of Service

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I stub a service in my component. For now, I want to spy on all methods and not actually call them.

I followed the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/testing#services-with-dependencies) which creates a spy object and then defines the return function:

```
  it('#getValue should return stubbed value from a spy', () => {
    // create `getValue` spy on an object representing the ValueService
    const valueServiceSpy =
      jasmine.createSpyObj('ValueService', ['getValue']);

    // set the value to return when the `getValue` spy is called.
    const stubValue = 'stub value';
    valueServiceSpy.getValue.and.returnValue(stubValue);
```

Instead of returning a defined value I want to call through on this particular method. I also moved the spy to beforeEach because I want to use it on multiple tests. The reason I don't want to mock the form creation is, that it would be a 1:1 copy of the original method.

### Spec

```
describe('GeneratorComponent', () => {
  let component: GeneratorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GeneratorComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const hotkeysServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HotkeysService', ['add']);
    const generatorServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GeneratorService', [
      'createGeneratorForm',
      'createRepository',
      'crawlRepository',
      'fillWithDummy'
    ]);
    generatorServiceSpy.createGeneratorForm.and.callThrough();
...

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GeneratorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

### Component

```
constructor(
    private generatorService: GeneratorService,
    ...
  ) {
    this.generatorForm = generatorService.createGeneratorForm();
    this.generatorForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe( (changes) => {
    ...  
    });
```

Now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined`.

Questions:

1) How to just call through this one particular method which creates my form?

2) Would this call through require me to import/provide all the dependencies of the service (service constructor) or just the dependencies of this particular method?

Answer (score 1):

I found several options:

A)

1. Create the original Service
2. Create the SpyObj.
3. Override the form creation method of the SpyObj with the original method

This is imho not the best approach, because it requires to import all the dependencies of the service to the Testbed.

B)

Redefine the form method in the spec e.g.

```
const generatorServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GeneratorService', [
      'createRepository',
      'crawlRepository',
      'fillWithDummy'
    ]);
    const formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    generatorServiceSpy.createGeneratorForm = (generator?: Generator) => {
      console.log('generator', generator);
      const generatorForm = formBuilder.group({
        url: [null]
      });
      if (generator) { generatorForm.patchValue(generator); }
      return generatorForm;
    };
```

This one might be helpful if a simplified version of the method is better for testing. The disadvantage is that it is not very dry.

c) This is my preferred solution. It combines minimal dependency declarations with the original functionality.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const generatorServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GeneratorService', [
        'createRepository',
        'crawlRepository',
        'fillWithDummy'
    ]);
    const formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    generatorServiceSpy.createGeneratorForm = GeneratorService.prototype.createReviewForm;
```